# how many lines of code does my class library have

Tags: .net, silverlight, metrics

for metrics reasons I need to know how many lines of code my class library has.  I'm doing this for code coverage....

So if Class library 1 has 50 lines of code and 100% coverage
And if Class library 2 has 500 lines of code and 0% coverage

My total coverage is 90%

Any idea how to do this?  Is there a utility or a way to use Visual Studio?

Comment: why don't you just count the lines? That's how we usually get a line count. ;)

Comment: This is not really a `unit-testing` question, therefore I removed the tag.

Comment: Does the closest guess win a prize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which VS version and edition do you have? It's built into 2008 Team Developer and 2010 Premium and Ultimate under Analyze->Calculate Code Metrics.

Answer (score 0):

Run nCover using the Testdriven.net plugin. It will show you the coveragde %

http://www.testdriven.net/